# C++ binary files not read correctly

Tags: c++, io, endianness

I am reading a file that is written in high endian on a little endian intel processor in c++. The file is a generic file written in binary. I have tried reading it using open() and fopen() both but they both seem to get the same thing wrong. The file is a binary file for training images from the MNIST dataset. It contains 4 headers, each 32 bits in size and stored in high endian. My code is working, it is just not giving the right value for the 2nd header. It works for the rest of the headers. I even opened the file in a hex editor to see if the value might be wrong but it is right. The program, for some weird reason, reads only the value of the second header wrong:
Here is the code that deals with reading the headers only:

```
void DataHandler::readInputData(std::string path){
    uint32_t headers[4];
    char bytes[4];
    std::ifstream file;
    //I tried both open() and fopen() as seen below
    file.open(path.c_str(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
    //FILE* f = fopen(path.c_str(), "rb");
    if (file)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 4)//4 headers
        {
            //if (fread(bytes, sizeof(bytes), 1, f))
            //{
            //    headers[i] = format(bytes);
            //    ++i;
            //}
            file.read(bytes, sizeof(bytes));
            headers[i++] = format(bytes);
        }
        printf("Done getting images file header.\n");
        printf("magic: 0x%08x\n", headers[0]);
        printf("nImages: 0x%08x\n", headers[1]);//THIS IS THE ONE THAT IS GETTING READ WRONG
        printf("rows: 0x%08x\n", headers[2]);
        printf("cols: 0x%08x\n", headers[3]);
        exit(1);
        //reading rest of the file code here
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid Input File Path\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

//converts high endian to little indian (required for Intel Processors)
uint32_t DataHandler::format(const char * bytes) const
{
    return (uint32_t)((bytes[0] << 24) |
        (bytes[1] << 16) |
        (bytes[2] << 8) |
        (bytes[3]));
}
```

Output I am getting is:

```
Done getting images file header.
magic: 0x00000803
nImages: 0xffffea60
rows: 0x0000001c
cols: 0x0000001c
```

nImages should be 60,000 or (0000ea60)h in hex but it is reading it as ffff... for some reason.
Here is the file opened in a hex editor:
[image: File in hex editor]
As we can see, the 2nd 32 bit number is 0000ea60 but it is reading it wrong...

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `char` is signed in your environment and therefore `0xEA` in the data is sign-extended to `0xFFFFFFEA`.
This will break the higher digits.

To prevent this, you should use `unsigned char` instead of `char`. (for both of element type of `bytes` and the argument of `format()`)

Comment: I see. I have two questions then. First, why does the char variable have a sign? Second, I tried to change both to unsigned but now I can't use fopen to read since it requires char *. What should I use to read it?

Comment: First, I don't know why `char` has a sign but whether `char` has a sign is implementation-defined. Second, you didn't use `fopen` in your posted code but `file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(bytes), sizeof(bytes));` will work.